# Prove $f(1)-f(-1)>f'\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+f'\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

Suppose the 5th order derivative function of $f(x)$ ,say, $f^{(5)}(x)>0$ for $x\in [-1,1]$.Prove $f(1)-f(-1)>f'\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+f'\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.

I know this can be done directly by **Gauss-Legendre formula**, but does there exist a more elementary proof?

Comment: While I can see what you have in mind with the Gauss-Legendre formula, you must be using a rather ideosyncratic definition of "directly". Some context would certainly help to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: The function cannot be even but can be odd : in this last case it leads to $f(1)>f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ . I don't know if we can start a proof starting from the odd case . Good luck .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think this problem can concern you have you an idea to prove it ? What is the significance of the fifth derivative here (some physical meaning?).Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its quite a rough idea but:
$$f^{(5)}(x)>0$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)>C_1$$
$$f^{(3)}(x)>C_1x+C_2$$
$$f''(x)>\frac {C_1}2x^2+C_2x+C_3$$
$$f'(x)>\frac{C_1}6x^3+\frac{C_2}2x^2+C_3x+C_4$$
$$f(x)>\frac{C_1}{24}x^4+\frac{C_2}6x^3+\frac{C_3}2x^2+C_4x+C_5$$

so:
$$f(1)-f(-1)>\frac{C_2}3+2C_4$$
$$f'(-3^{-1/2})+f'(3^{-1/2})>\frac{C_2}6+2C_4$$
and so this suggests it can be true, however I have no upper limit so this is not really a proof :(